# Sort sections alphabetically in Powerpoint using VBA

Tags: vba, sorting, powerpoint, sections

I have a big PowerPoint file with many sections and I keep adding some.

I am looking for a way to sort my sections by alphabetical order.

I am sure it's doable using VBA but my knowledge are limited and I couldn't find a similar code to adapt.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on a classic array-sort-logic - but applied to the sections.

No idea if this is a performance issue if you have a lot of sections.

```vb
Sub sortSections()

Dim sp As SectionProperties
Set sp = ActivePresentation.SectionProperties

Dim cntSections As Long
cntSections = sp.Count

Dim i As Long, j As Long
For i = 1 To cntSections - 1
    For j = i + 1 To cntSections
        If UCase(sp.Name(i)) > UCase(sp.Name(j)) Then
            sp.Move j, i
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```